# How many punches will it take for a 100 joule punch to reach 210 petajoules if the strength doubles every punch?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$100$ Joule Punch doubles every time you hit, goal to get $210$ petajoules.
How many punches will it take?

I actually tried converting $100$ joule to petajoules, powering $x$ and then solving with ln it actually didn't work. I really want to know how many punches will it take and I want to know why $ln$ does not work.

Even if $100$ joules are exactly $0.000000000000$ pj still doesn't work with $ln$.

Comment: petajoules equals to $10^{15}j$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with $\log_2$:

$$\log_2 (210 \cdot 10^{15}) - \log_2 (50) \doteq 51.9,$$

so $52$ punches (starting at the punch before assuming the first punch is $100$ J).

Windows 10 calculator will do the doubling for you, by the way.